# Возможно ли программно изменить язык ввода?

Tags: android

Есть несколько полей для ввода. В одно из полей нужно вводить данные только на английском.

Возможно ли как то сделать так, что бы именно для этого поля, язык ввода сам изменился на Английский?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это возможно сделать следующим образом: можно ограничить ввод для пользователя набором конкретных символов, делается с помощью свойства **digits** в **xml**`ке.

Пример:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/nameText"
    android:layout_width="177dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" />
```

[источник](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12171676/prevent-other-language-except-english-in-edittext)

там же кстати есть мысль использовать **TextWatcher**, с помощью которого стирать в **EdtiText**`е не английские символы

Comment: Дополню способом без xml

InputType.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
editText.setKeyListener(DigitsKeyListener.getInstance("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ."));

Comment: Спасибо. Это один из подходящих вариантов. О подобном я думал. Просто хотелось что бы язык клавиатуры к тому же сам по себе изменялся